# codeblocks gives incorrect result as output

Tags: c

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a = 5;
    int b,c;
    if (a==4){
        b = 6;
        c = 7;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n",b,c);
}
```

I know result should be 0 0, but codeblocks giving answer 50 8. I tried online compiler and I got answer 0 0. So what is problem with codeblocks? I am using latest version of codeblocks and gcc c compiler. How can I avoid this kind of problems in future?

Comment: "I know result should be 0 0", the result of reading uninitialized variables is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Why do you think so..... Variables with automatic storage are not zeroed.

Comment: Initialise the variables to zero

Comment: Please don't be too hasty blaming the tools.

Comment: *How can I avoid this kind of problems in future?* By reading the manual, not making assumptions and writing better code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of `b` and `c` variables are garbage because `if()` condition become `false`. It means, it is undefined behaviours.

**C11  section 6.7.9 Initialization :**

**Paragraph 10:**

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Comment: What does it mean "explicitly"?

Comment: @CIsForCookies you can drop that word. You can actually read it as _If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized, its value is indeterminate_.

Answer (score 1):

> I know result should be 0 0

Your guess is wrong

The variables `b,c` are **automatic** (storage specifier), **uninitialized** variables -> indeterminate values -> no guarantee on their values -> **UB**!

In your case you got `50,8` you might as well get other values / print garbage/ crash...

Comment: Default value of integers is 0, isn't it?

Comment: @Magic105 no, not for automatic variables, only for static and global variables..

Comment: for statics and globals - Yes. For local (auto) - No

Answer (score 0):

The values for b and c are undefined in this program as they dont get initialised before they get printed

Comment: "The values for b and c are undefined" the problem goes deeper than that.

Comment: default value of integers is 0, isn't it?

Comment: @Magic105 Where did you get that info? :)

Comment: The values are not assigned before printing, so they can be anything when those variables get printed

Comment: @Magic105 zero is for global variables, for local variables, it can be anything(garbage values), so you need to explicitly assign variables with some values prior to useng the variables

Answer (score 0):

Okay looking at your code and analyzing it step by step,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int a = 5;//You've assigned the value of 5 to integer a.
        int b,c;//You've declared two integer variables "b" and "c".
        if (a==4)/*Compiler checks whether the if condition is true,which in your  case is not*/
        {
            b = 6;/*Assigning value 6 to the b variable but no effect as the if condition of your's is not satisfied*/

            c = 7;/*The same above condition applies here.*/
        }
        printf("%d %d\n",b,c);/*Here your trying to print the values of b and c, 

But remember you have not given them any value. So the compiler automatically prints the garbage value(random value). It need not be 0 all the time.*/  

return 0;//You forgot this step btw:)
    }
```